# MS Access - Add OLE objects to table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2016 and Office 2016.

I have a form named "frmFiles". On that form I have a bound object frame named "FileOLE" and a button named "Command2".
I have a table named "tblFiles" with 2 fields in it. One named "ID" (AutoNumber/Primary key) and a second named "File" (OLE Object).

My form's RecordSource is linked to my table, and my bound object frame control's ControlSource to my table's "File" field.

My goal is to append the same Excel worksheet to my table each time I click the "Command2" button.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Me.FileOLE.Class = "Excel.Sheet"
    Me.FileOLE.OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEmbedded
    Me.FileOLE.SourceDoc = <My worksheet's full path>
    Me.FileOLE.Action = acOLECreateEmbed
    Me.FileOLE.SizeMode = acOLESizeZoom
End Sub
```

This works only for the first click. It will add the worksheet to the empty table. After that, all subsequent clicks will fail to append the file to the table.

What I am missing if that is even possible to accomplish?

Thanks.

Comment: Review https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/872418-button-attach-file-object-ole-field and http://lebans.com/oletodisk.htm

Comment: Why are you embedding the same workbook multiple times?

Comment: Trying your code but get compile error "method or data member not found". Is there more code? Do I need to set a reference library?

Comment: You probably need to move/make a new record if you want to upload multiple times.

Comment: @June7, The workbook acts as a template. Each one holds a worksheet containing specific data.

Comment: @June7, No there is not more code nor references to add.

Comment: @krish KM, I tried that but it just adds an empty record and no worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.